# Unresolved external pow10 in C++Builder 64bit

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

We are migrating code to the Clang-based 64-bit compiler in C++Builder 10.2.3.

The linker is complaining about an unresolved external for `pow10()`, which is in `math.h`, but apparently we need a lib that isn't being linked.

Does anyone know which one it is?

Comment: `-lm`, usually.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, it is not linked in. I dumped cw64.a and it does not contain that function.

There is an alternative:

```
double d = pow10l(2);
```

That will compile and link fine, and give the correct result, `100.0`. The result is supposed to be a `long double`, but that maps to `double` in Win64, so that works fine.

---

*FWIW, there is also a function `_pow10()`, but that is for internal use only. It seems to be a helper function for `pow10l()` and some other functions.*